# Convert any integration region to a rectangle

Tags: integration, differential-forms

I've been studying double integrals from the point of view of
differential forms and pullbacks. In my book there's an example of how
to convert a triangular region of integration between points (0, 0), (0,
1) and (1, 0) with line $x + y =1$ into a rectangular integration region
in variables $u, v$. If $\alpha$ is the map from the rectangular region
to the triangular region, its pullback $\alpha^{*}$ works as
$\alpha^{*}x = uv$ and $\alpha^{*}y = u(1 - v)$.

This change in terms of $u$ and $v$ does not seem intuitive at all for
me. My question is: is there a reasoning that you can use to convert any
region of integration to a rectangular region?

Comment: Not if the region has a hole. E.g., an annulus.

Comment: Thanks. Otherwise, is there a procedure to transform from any region to a rectangular region?

Comment: Any simply-connected region can be transformed into a rectangle, but for complicated regions, the function will not be some nice substitution that is going to be useful for integration. Instead it will be a nasty result of limiting processes.